# a specific css just for printing View

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage that has a lot of images and rednant text and adds in it. O don't want these to appear when the user prints the page, IS it possible to specify a specific CSS file for the page desgin in print mode, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the target medium within the document language. For example, in HTML 4 ([HTML4]), the "media" attribute on the LINK element specifies the target media of an external style sheet:

[check this out](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css media queries for this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```